# nestedSortable add class when it becoems a sub item

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-sortable

So if been trying to add an class to the 'li' when it comes a sub item.

the class im trying to add is mjs-nestedSortable-no-nesting so you cannot have sub items inside sub items.

```
              <ol class="sortable ui-sortable mjs-nestedSortable-branch mjs-nestedSortable-expanded">
                <li style="display: list-item;" class="mjs-nestedSortable-leaf" id="menuItem_<?=$row['MAINCATID']; ?>">
                      <div class="menuDiv">
                        <span>
                          <span data-id="<?=$row['MAINCATID']; ?>" class="itemTitle"><input type="text" class="form-control vasteWidth inputNamen" value="<?=$row['MAINCATNAAM']; ?>"></span>
                          <span title="Click to delete item." data-id="<?=$row['MAINCATID']; ?>" class="deleteMenu pull-right fa fa-times-circle fa-3x"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <ol>
                          <li style="display: list-item;" class="mjs-nestedSortable-no-nesting" id="menuItem_<?=$s['MAINCATID']; ?>">
                            <div class="menuDiv">
                              <span>
                                <span data-id="<?=$s['SUBCATID']; ?>" class="itemTitle"><input type="text" class="form-control vasteWidth inputNamen" value="<?=$s['SUBCATNAAM']; ?>"></span>
                                <span title="Click to delete item." data-id="<?=$s['SUBCATID']; ?>" class="deleteMenu pull-right fa fa-times-circle fa-3x"></span>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                      </ol>
                  </li>
              </ol>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote?

Comment: Hello Nir, i added the html code that i use (left most of the php stuff out that sorts if its a sub cat or not). For javascript i use pretty much the default code, i know that i need to use the update event adding the class but i dont know where to start.